# Mixed-effects model of nested time series

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I have time series data for a variable from different climate models, each with multiple runs using different initial conditions (ensemble members). A small subset of the data to see how its laid out (the compete dataset includes 36 years and 19 models with between 5 and 49 members each).

```
#>      member         model  time          hgt
#>      <fctr>        <char> <int>        <num>
#>  1: 1.1.1.1    ACCESS-CM2  1979 -0.045225795
#>  2: 1.1.1.1    ACCESS-CM2  1980 -0.009871858
#>  3: 1.1.1.1    ACCESS-CM2  1981 -0.062349852
#>  4: 2.1.1.1    ACCESS-CM2  1979 -0.051631382
#>  5: 2.1.1.1    ACCESS-CM2  1980 -0.043643211
#>  6: 2.1.1.1    ACCESS-CM2  1981 -0.029604119
#>  7: 1.1.1.1 ACCESS-ESM1-5  1979 -0.009869267
#>  8: 1.1.1.1 ACCESS-ESM1-5  1980 -0.014024862
#>  9: 1.1.1.1 ACCESS-ESM1-5  1981 -0.016568455
#> 10: 2.1.1.1 ACCESS-ESM1-5  1979 -0.008007551
#> 11: 2.1.1.1 ACCESS-ESM1-5  1980 -0.009915181
#> 12: 2.1.1.1 ACCESS-ESM1-5  1981 -0.015526597
#> 13: 1.1.1.1 AWI-CM-1-1-MR  1979 -0.030887150
#> 14: 1.1.1.1 AWI-CM-1-1-MR  1980 -0.036778999
#> 15: 1.1.1.1 AWI-CM-1-1-MR  1981 -0.028872595
#> 16: 2.1.1.1 AWI-CM-1-1-MR  1979 -0.046219117
#> 17: 2.1.1.1 AWI-CM-1-1-MR  1980 -0.024323372
#> 18: 2.1.1.1 AWI-CM-1-1-MR  1981 -0.024374409
```

I want to model the linear trend, considering uncertainty in both ensemble members and models. To do this, I plan to use mixed-effects modeling, treating ensemble members as random effects (because they are a random sample of the population of possible model runs) and models as fixed effects (models are not random and not sampled from a larger population).

**First question**: Is my reasoning reasonable? Am I missing something?

So, now to code that in R. I’m using lme4 and if I understood the documentation correctly, I think I need to use a formula like this:

```r
library(lme4)
model <- lmer(hgt ~ time*model + (time | model/member), data = data) 
#> boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
```

So, fixed effect of time interacting with model, so that the slope (and intercept) can vary among models, plus a random effect for `member`, which are nested in `model` so that each member can have also a random slope (and intercept).

**Second question**: Is this formula correct?

Two issues I have with this approach is that I don’t get an average `time` effect, instead I get a single slop for each model.

**Third question**: How can I get an average slope and its uncertainty? Do I need to consider model effects as random since I’m somewhat assuming that there is a “mean slope” that governs the distribution of the model effect?

The second issue is that I get a warning that the fit is singular. I tested for collinearity and found some duplicated members in a model, but I removed it in this data, so that is not the issue.

```r
# Highest four correlations between all time series 
data %>% 
  data.table::copy() %>% 
  .[, member := interaction(model, member)] %>% 
  widyr::pairwise_cor(member, time, hgt, sort = TRUE, upper = FALSE) %>% 
  data.table::as.data.table() %>% 
  head(4)
#>                     item1                 item2 correlation
#>                    <fctr>                <fctr>       <num>
#> 1: ACCESS-ESM1-5.14.1.1.1      CanESM5.11.1.1.1   0.6410348
#> 2: ACCESS-ESM1-5.40.1.1.1        MIROC6.5.1.1.1   0.6364663
#> 3:    CNRM-CM6-1.10.1.1.2 MPI-ESM1-2-HR.5.1.1.1   0.6300627
#> 4:         CESM2.10.1.1.1         NESM3.2.1.1.1   0.6281228
```

**Fourth question**: Is this serious? What could be causing the issue?

<sup>Created on 2024-01-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers shows how to accept one's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2. I disagree with @DrJerryTAO's answer for this question. Specifically, I agree that your model *is* wrong/problematic, but disagree about the solution. I would suggest

```r
hgt ~ time*model + (1 + time | model:member)
```

- `time*model` captures the different intercepts and slopes for each model. I agree with your argument for specifying `model` as a fixed effect, but more specifically you are probably interested in *making inferences about the differences in intercepts and slopes between particular models*, which requires that you treat them as a fixed effect.
- the problem with your random effect was using `model/member` as the grouping variable(s) rather than `model:member`. The former (`model/member`) expands to `model + model:member`; the first term there (`model`) is redundant with the fixed-effect terms in your model (that is, you are including variation in intercepts and slopes among models in your model *twice*, once as a fixed effect and once as a random effect).

3. If you specify *sum-to-zero* contrasts for `model` (e.g. by adding `contrasts = list(model = contr.sum)` to your argument list), then the intercept will represent the average intercept across models and the slope will represent the average slope. You can also achieve this *post hoc* using the `emmeans` package.
4. Singular fits are a big can of worms, search on CrossValidated or read `?lme4::isSingular` or the [relevant section of the GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#singular-fits). The short version is that you aren't necessarily doing anything wrong, and it doesn't necessarily mean there's a problem — it may just mean that the best fit to your model is consistent with there being *no* variation across grouping variables in some dimension. (However, I'd fix the model specification first before thinking about it any more, in any case ...)

Comment: Ah, thanks about the `model/member` thing. With `time * model + (1 | model:member)` I'm still getting the `isSingular()` bit and the variance of the random effects is indeed zero. Great about contrasts, although with that I'm getting `Warning: Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling`.

Comment: The warning is useful. As I mentioned, "sometimes we also need to center and scale predictors to achieve convergence, such as using I((time - 1990)/10) instead of time."

Answer (score 1):

> First question: Is my reasoning reasonable? Am I missing something? Do I need to consider model effects as random since I’m somewhat assuming that there is a “mean slope” that governs the distribution of the model effect?

Yes. Modeling ensemble members as random effects and both model type and data year as fixed effects is okay. However, it is also possible to have model type as random effects if we consider that the model types used in the data are a sample of all possible model specifications. Whether to use model type as random or fixed effects depends on the plausibility of the assumption that the effect of model types are independent from all other fixed-effect (regular) predictors in the formula (i.e. `time` in your case). If there are tens of model types (to ensure a reliable variance-component estimate) and they are reasonably argued to be uncorrelated with data year (effects of model types do not vary across data years), then we can have random effects of model types. It is not reliable to model data year as random effects if there are only three unique values of years: 1979, 1980, and 1981. If both model type and data year are essentially discrete categories, it is difficult (though possible) to model both random and fixed effects of them at the same time.

> Second question: Is this formula correct?

No. You indicated that there are 36 years. This means we may need many polynomial terms to represent time effects accurately to meet the linearity assumption of the model. If we model (1) fixed effects of `time`, (2) fixed effects of `model`, (3) random effects of `member`, we should use a formula `lmer(hgt ~ (time + I(time^2) + I(time^3) + ...) * factor(model) + (1 | member), data = data)` . We should not nest effects of `member` in `model` using `(1| model/member)`, as they cross: Different categories of `member` appear within the same `model` while  different categories of `model` appear within the same `member`. If we model random effects of `model`, the formula should be `lmer(hgt ~ time + I(time^2) + I(time^3) + ... + (1 | member) + （1 | factor(model)), data = data)` . The specification `hgt ~ time * model + (1 + time | model:member)` suggested by Ben Bolker is also attractive. But if we need multiple polynomial terms to represent time effects, allowing random effects of these many time terms correlated with the random intercept and each other can make the estimation unstable. Another reasonable specification is `lmer(hgt ~ (time + I(time^2) + I(time^3) + ... ) * factor(model) + (1 | member:model), data = data)` so there is only one random-intercept term but no random slopes, making the model more parsimonious and stable to estimate.

> Third question: How can I get an average slope and its uncertainty?

It is unclear why you want “an average time effect” and what it refers to. You will get one single coefficient of `time` because the data sample shows it is integer, a continuous variable. If there are only three unique values of `time`, it is better to treat it as a discrete categorical variable, using `factor(time)`. You will get two distinct coefficients of `time` in this way, corresponding to `time == 1980` and `time == 1981` respectively. Since it is a linear model, the coefficients directly show average marginal effects: How much `hgt` changes moving from `time == 1979` to `time == 1980` and from `time == 1979` to `time == 1981`. If there are 36 unique values of `time`, it is beneficial to examine its effects as a discrete categorical variable, using `factor(time)`, so we can determine the shape of the curve to which polynomial terms of time have to fit. Changing the contrast suggested by Ben Bolker works but is unfamiliar to most audience. Presenting coefficients under such special contrasts requires deliberate explanation and may confuse reviewers. Presenting the contrasts not through coefficients but through prediction after fitting, through `emmeans` and `marginaleffects`, is much easier to understand.

> Fourth question: Is this serious? What could be causing the issue?

Yes. (Perfect) collinearity can be the reason for singularity (taking the inverse of Hessian to get `vcov()` is as if dividing by zero). In your case, it is due to an oversaturated specification in the model matrix instead of the original data: too complex a model specification than what the data allows for accurate estimation. As Ben explains, `(time | model/member)` makes the fixed effect of `model` redundant, analogue to the collinearity issue. You should also check the confidence intervals to see if there are any boundary issues (confidence limits too close to theoretical boundaries), such as the lower limit of a standard deviation of random effects very close to zero. Sometimes we also need to center and scale predictors to achieve convergence, such as using `I((time - 1990)/10)` instead of `time`.

Comment: I edited my question to make the total size of the dataset more clear. I have 36 years in total, not just 3. 
with `hgt ~ factor(time) * factor(model) + (1 | member)` don't I lose the fact that different members belong to different models?

Comment: Answer updated with your new facts. What do you mean that "I lose the fact that different members belong to different models?" I explained that "We should not nest effects of member in model using (1| model/member), as they cross."

Comment: I mean that there are multipole 1.1.1.1 members (one for each model), so there's one population for each group of members. But wouldn't `(1 | member)` treat all member effects as random samples of the same population?
By "average time effect" I mean something like the average slope along members. (I want to model a linear trend, though, so I think I won't be using higher polynomial terms)

Comment: `+ (1 | member)` will give each member category a special intercept deviation--when observations share the same group member, they have unexplained commonality represented by this intercept deviation. To include model type effects, you can add a second random intercept, `+ (1 | model)`. This way intercept has three terms: common mean, member deviation, model deciation. If you assume a linear time trend, then the coefficient of the time term is the average AND marginal time effect, since you have a linear model. But linearity is a strong assumption. You should at least test nonlinear effects.